# Usage of loc for lists in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the following pandas dataframe with a single row:

```
data = [[['A'], '0', ['B']]]
dffsm = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['State', 'Trigger', 'NextState'])
```

The following line would filter the row properly, as the datatype is string:

```
dffsm.loc[dffsm['Trigger'] == '0']
```

However, a similar line would not filter the row based on a particular list:

```
dffsm.loc[dffsm['State'] == ['A']]
```

Interestingly, `dffsm.at[0,'State']` yields `['A']`, but `.loc` would not filter the same value.

What do I have to do if I want to filter a pandas column containing lists based on a list?

Comment: In your case, `['A']` is broadcast to the whole dataframe. Try  `dffsm['State'].apply(lambda x: x==['A'])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use isin and then do a double parenthesis around the value to search for

```
dffsm.loc[dffsm['State'].isin([['A']])]
```

```
    State   Trigger     NextState
0   [A]         0       [B]
```

Comment: Many thanks. I wonder how come the bare .loc does not work with a list, but works with an integer or string. Any reference that sheds light on this?